# How do I create a Rule "When role is removed, send email to the user"?

Tags: rules, users

I am trying to create a rule that sends an email to the user when a role has been removed from their account. I can't seem to find a rule reaction under User "When role is removed". How do I create a rule to do this?

Comment: You can do it by `hook_user`.

Comment: is there no way to get this done just using the rules UI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has to be triggered when a particular role ("subscriber") has been removed. So we can use 2 conditions **User has role(s)**, to check if he had the role *before the edit*, and that he doesn't have it *after the edit* :

1st condition : selector "account_unchanged", check the role "subscriber" (here test)

2nd condition : selector "account", check the same role, and **negate**.

[image]

Comment: What if he removed one role and added another one, then your condition will fail. And also what if the OP wanted to trigger the mail whenever the particular role was removed(I think that's what the OP has asked.) However +1 for your approach :)

Comment: The particular situation is when a user gets their "subscriber" role removed. There are other roles on the site that can be added and removed that shouldn't get this email when those are removed.

Comment: If he wants to check that a particular role has been removed, it's even simplier :
1. Add condition "User has role(s)" with **account_unchanged** and select the role,
2. Add condition "User has role(s)" with **account** (NOT the unchanged) and NEGATE.

Comment: I edit my answer to fit to that.