# How can I send an email to Administrator when Users change their name?

Tags: rules, users, emails

We are using LoginToboggan. How can I send an email to Administrator when Users change their name?

I looked at Rules, but the only Rule action which seems close is

"After updating an existing user account"

Is there a (simple) way to program a custom action which sees that the Name field has been changed?

TIA

`{ "rules_notify_sales_on_username_change" : {
    "LABEL" : "Notify Sales/Administrator On Username Change",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "email" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "mimemail" ],
    "ON" : { "user_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "account" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "11" : "11", "7" : "7", "2" : "2" } },
          "operation" : "OR"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mimemail_to_users_of_role" : {
          "key" : "userupdate-sales",
          "roles" : { "value" : { "6" : "6", "3" : "3", "20" : "20" } },
          "active" : 1,
          "from_name" : "User Update",
          "subject" : "User updated their account information",
          "body" : "An existing user has updated their account. \r\n[account:name] \r\n[account:mail] ",
          "plaintext" : "An existing user has updated their account. ",
          "language_user" : 0,
          "language" : [ "account:language" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes in Rules you can achieve it

**Step 1 :** In Events Event add "**After updating an existing user account**"

**Step 2  :** Conditions Elements "**Execute custom PHP code** "

**return [account-unchanged:name] != [account:name]**

or add **data comparison** and add

**Data to compare** Selected data: account-unchanged:name

**Operator** : equals

**Data value** : account:name

**Step 3:** In action send mail

refer this for same kind of problem with role. but you have is name

[How do I create a Rule "When role is removed, send email to the user"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52579/how-do-i-create-a-rule-when-role-is-removed-send-email-to-the-user?rq=1)